# Skyrim Soul Trapping

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have learned soul trap, my smithing is 60, my enchanting around 40 or 50 (I can do the soul syphon). Yet I go to the enchanting table and I do not get the option to put soul trap on a weapon. please let me know!

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have Soul Trap listed on your list of enchantments and cannot set it?  Or, is it not listed under possible enchantments?

Answer (score 6):

The only thing that determines your ability to lay a particular enchantment on a weapon is whether you have disenchanted a weapon with such an enchantment before. Find a weapon that has a soul trap enchantment and disenchant it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put a spell on a weapon like in Oblivion. You have to learn the relevant enchantment by using the table to disenchant an item that already has that property.